# how to make input prompt for 7 column by ifstream

Tags: c++

I typed in a file name which I want to show on prompt screen but it says that
"'c:\test\sp.csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"
even though the file is available on the path.

1 - Why did this error happen? How to fix it?

C:\Users\MS>c:\test\sp.csv
'c:\test\sp.csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

2 - The code below only shows one column, if I want to input for 7 columns, how would I edit the code below?

How to print out on prompt screen using ifstream for 7 column with header and price.

> ```
> Date      Open    High    Low Close       Volume      Adj Close
> 6/21/2013 1588.62 1599.19 1577.7  1592.43     5797280000  1592.43
> 6/20/2013 1624.62 1624.62 1584.32 1588.19     4858850000  1588.19
> ```

```
int main(){

    int open;

    string fileName;
    cout <<"Enter a file name: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);  //c:\\test\\sp.csv

    ifstream inFile(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);   

     while(!inFile.eof()){
      inFile >> open;  
      cout << open << endl;
     }
     inFile.close();    
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0; 
}
```

Thank you Kelly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on Windows OS

1. `.csv` file extension is not an executable one. It won't get "executed", even if its present in current working directory/folder.

Probably what you want is a `.exe`, `.com` or `.bat` file.

Here, in this case I think you want your .CPP 's executable with command line argument.

May be something like

`C:\Users\MS>c:\test\sp.exe c:\test\sp.csv'` Considering your C++ file name is `sp.cpp`

2 . Looks like you want to display out all contents of `sp.scv`

You may want to read the header first (i.e the Titles), and then read the values.
There are lot of question already asked on StackOverflow, related to this, please refer them.

Also for proper formatting you may want to use `std::setw`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new programming and site , where I can find the article related my question, what question title I should type.